# Pandas groupby using range and type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe where I have "room_type" and "review_scores_rating" as labels

The dataframe looks like this

```
room_type   review_scores_rating
0   Private room    98.0
1   Private room    89.0
2   Entire home/apt 100.0
3   Private room    99.0
4   Private room    97.0
```

I already use groupby so I also have this dataframe

```
               review_scores_rating
room_type   
Entire home/apt 11930
Hotel room  97
Private room    3116
Shared room 44
```

I want to create a dataframe where I have as columns the different room types and each row counts how many are in for different ranges of the rating

I was able to get to this point

```
                     count
review_scores_rating    
(19.92, 30.0]         24
(30.0, 40.0]          23
(40.0, 50.0]          9
(50.0, 60.0]          97
(60.0, 70.0]          74
(70.0, 80.0]          486
(80.0, 90.0]          1701
(90.0, 100.0]        12773
```

But I don´t know how to make it count not only by range of the score but also for room type so I can now for example how many private room have a review score rating between 30 and 40

Comment: Why don't you provide your current code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with [`cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
pd.crosstab(pd.cut(df['review_scores_rating'], bins=range(0, 101, 10)),
            df['room_type'])
```

Output:

```
room_type             Entire home/apt  Private room
review_scores_rating                               
(80, 90]                            0             1
(90, 100]                           1             3
```

Or [`groupby.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html):

```
df.groupby(['room_type', pd.cut(df['review_scores_rating'], bins=range(0, 101, 10))]).count()
```

Output:

```
                                      review_scores_rating
room_type       review_scores_rating                      
Entire home/apt (0, 10]                                  0
                (10, 20]                                 0
                (20, 30]                                 0
                (30, 40]                                 0
                (40, 50]                                 0
                (50, 60]                                 0
                (60, 70]                                 0
                (70, 80]                                 0
                (80, 90]                                 0
                (90, 100]                                1
Private room    (0, 10]                                  0
                (10, 20]                                 0
                (20, 30]                                 0
                (30, 40]                                 0
                (40, 50]                                 0
                (50, 60]                                 0
                (60, 70]                                 0
                (70, 80]                                 0
                (80, 90]                                 1
                (90, 100]                                3
```